# How to bind service value with directive scope so that view updates when model changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm using an `isAuthenticated` value in my service. For some reason, it won't update the view when the service model changes.

```
app.factory('AuthService', function($timeout) {
    var isAuthenticated = false;

    $timeout(function () {
        isAuthenticated = true; }, 2000);

    return {
       data: {'isLoggedIn': isAuthenticated}
    }
});

app.directive('appMainMenu', function (AuthService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.model = AuthService;
        }
    };
});
```

Then the HTML:

```
<div app-main-menu>
    <a href="#login" ng-show="!model.data.isLoggedIn">Guest can Login</a>
    <a href="#logout" ng-show="model.data.isLoggedIn">Member can Logout</a>
</div>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Before I was using a function but that does recursive loop (stops after 10th time) on every $digest, so I don't think that's the right way to do it. It's a method someone on here suggested to me a while back.

It looks like:

```
app.factory('AuthService', function($timeout) {
    var isAuthenticated = false;

    $timeout(function () {
        isAuthenticated = true; }, 2000);

    return {
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            return isAuthenticated;
        }
    }
});

app.directive('appMainMenu', function (AuthService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.isLoggedIn = function () {
                return AuthService.isLoggedIn();
            };
        }
    };
});

<div app-main-menu>
    <a href="#login" ng-show="!isLoggedIn()">Guest can Login</a>
    <a href="#logout" ng-show="isLoggedIn()">Member can Logout</a>
</div>
```

The end result is that works, but if you console.log(...) inside isLoggedIn() you'll see that it's firing 10 times on every $digest.

Comment: Instead of    scope.model = AuthService;    try using    scope.$apply(function(){  scope.model = AuthService  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not updated in the view because your service doesn't update it. :)

When your service is created by the factory function, the return value (which would become your service Object) is:

```
{ data: {'isLoggedIn': isAuthenticated} }
```

with `isAuthenticated` being the value that it was at the time you returned the object. It's equivalent to:

```
{ data: {'isLoggedIn': false} }
```

This is because `isAuthenticated` is a Boolean - a primitive value, that is assigned "by-value", not "by-reference".

If you did something like the following, it would work:

```
app.factory('AuthService', function($timeout) {
    var isAuthenticated = false;
    var svc = {data: {isLoggedIn: isAuthenticated }};
    $timeout(function () {
        svc.data.isAuthenticated = true; }, 2000);

    return svc;
});
```

Comment: Do I need to pass the entire `data` object like `$scope.data = AuthService.data` to be able to display the update variable in template? When I attach the variable directly to scope, the change doesn't propagate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I suggest you create another question if you have another issue.